# Spring security: How Spring security registers new session in SessionRegistry?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using custom authentication using spring security. I haven't used any AuthenticationProvider but using UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and authenticating user which is working fine. I want to get list of all logged in users which is possible using SessionRegistry. I want to know how SessionRegistry registers new session and how? I went through spring documentation which does not explain its working. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New session info will be added to SessionRegistry from using: **registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy** upon successful authentication.

To implement this, you need to first use **SessionRegistryImpl** for SessionRegistry bean.